# Dismiss a modal ViewController after X seconds

Tags: ios, swift

I have a login modal UIViewController open and what to show a second "Thank you" Viewcontroller modally for 60 seconds and then dismiss it, but I can figoure out how to do this in SWIFT. (It was easy in Objectiv C)

Here is my code for opening the "Thank you viewcontroller" after closing the first one.

```
        weak var pvc = self.presentingViewController
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        let thankYouExistingVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ThankYouExistingVC") as! ThankYouExistingVC
        pvc?.present(thankYouExistingVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
```

Comment: Do you want to dismiss `thankYouExistingVC`?

Comment: You should add your Objective C code to the question. It would further clarify what you’re attempting to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using `DisaptchQueue`:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 60) {
        // Do whatever you want
        theViewControllerToDismiss.dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It was something like this i also did. I used a timer Instead. I dont know if there is a difference ?

Comment: This way you directly use the main `dispatchQueue` without using an external system (the timer) that will in the end be using the queue. `Timer` are much better used for repeating things, or for more transversal usage (across your whole app, not just on the same view controller.)

Comment: This makes sense Zaphod. Thank for explaining :)

Answer (score -1):

I dont know why, but I always seem to find a way just after i ask the question here, no matter how long i have been searching.  This code worked for me. Sorry about that

For people that search the same as me.  This code closes the current viewcontroller and open a new one for 5 seconds before it closes it again.

Thank you all for trying to help <3

```
        weak var pvc = self.presentingViewController
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                let thankYouExistingVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ThankYouExistingVC") as! ThankYouExistingVC

            pvc?.present(thankYouExistingVC, animated: true, completion: {

                    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: false, block: {_ in
                        thankYouExistingVC.dismiss(animated: true) {

                        }
                    })
                })

        }
    )
```